# Cookie does not work in Mac Excel

Tags: office-js

We used to see a bug in Mac Excel 2016 that localStorage does not persist after add-in refresh. So we have adopted a work around by using cookie to store local data.

It works fine until recent Office update. It seems now Cookies does not survive the refresh of add-in. But fortunately localStorage started working.

Does Office team had some fixes to localStorage? But why you are dropping support of Cookies?

Comment: Let me check with the team.

Answer (score 0):

The localStorage issue was fixed with November release (15.28.0). We did not make any changes with cookies and they are persisting between sessions when I try. Could you provide a repro of the issue? What version of Office, Safari, and Mac OS are you seeing the cookie issue with?